# Swift iOS NSJsonSerialization fails silently

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, json, swift, api

I have the following code fetching json data via an API.

```
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        // print("Response: \(response)")
        // print("DATA: \(data)")

        if data != nil {
            do {


                print( NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))

                if let jsonResults =  try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSArray {
                    print("\n\nThe return JSON looks like this: \(jsonResults)\n\n")
                }
            } catch {
                print("\n\nProblem getting JSON back from GET API.\n\n")
            }

        }  else  {
           print("API Not Available")  // data was nil
        }

    }) // task

    task.resume()
```

The "print" of the NSString shows what to my eyes looks like valid JSON.  The console shows this as:

```
Optional({"id":15,"user_id":11,"breed_id":593,"gender":"Male","age_years":5,"tally":{"count":1246,"struvite":716,"calcium_oxalate":388,"urate":217,"calcium_phosphate":30,"silica":21,"compound":41},"created_at":"2016-02-04T08:26:14.719-06:00","updated_at":"2016-02-04T08:26:14.719-06:00"})
```

However, the "if let jsonResults =" statement does execute successfully (there is no jsonResults printed) and the catch does not execute either -- so it seems like a silent error.

A very similar call works on another part of the API.  The only big difference is that "tally" in the JSON return on this call is nested.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: The example data you pasted in your code is a Dictionary, not an Array. you need to cast it into a dictionary type e.g. `[String: Anyobject]` as suggested by [dzk](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35204049/5836843) below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer was a combination of dzk and ishaq's responses.

I replaced

```
if let jsonResults =  try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSArray
```

with:

```
if let jsonResults =  try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
```

The essential piece was casting it as a Dictionary, not an Array.

Answer (score 2):

The JSON may not be serialised properly, so try to replace:

```
if let jsonResults =  try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSArray
```

with:

```
if let jsonResults =  try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let jsonResults = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSMutableDictionary
```

This implementation is a lot neater, and you don't have to specify their data types.